# How do i toggle between black and white for my button?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a light mode button that changes the background and text of my website, and it works for everything except two buttons

I tried doing this. It worked but it would not toggle back to white when going back to dark mode.

```js
document.getElementById('next').style.color = "black";
document.getElementById('prev').style.color = "black";

function lightMode() {
    var prevButton = document.getElementById('prev');
    prevButton.classList.toggle("colorBlackWhenLight");
    
    var nextButton = document.getElementById('next');
    nextButton.classList.toggle("colorBlackWhenLight");
}
```

```css
.colorBlackWhenLight {
  color: var(--black);
}
```

```html
<a onclick="lightMode()" id="lightModeButton">Light</a>
<a id="prev" class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
<a id="next" class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
```

Comment: PS: Avoid using inline `on*` handlers. JS should be in one place only and that's the respective tag or file. Use addEventListener instead.

Comment: Try with an additional layer of selector specificity like: `#prev.colorBlackWhenLight, #next.colorBlackWhenLight { /* styles here*/ }`

Comment: It looks like there's a syntax error here - your function declaration should be `function lightMode() {` - you were missing the parentheses.

Comment: oh yeah i have that i forgot to write it here my bad @John

Comment: Do you have the `--black` variable defined in your CSS?

Comment: @RatajS yes i have

Comment: You shouldn't be using anchors for actions. This is a job for buttons (styled as you like). Anchors are for navigation.

Answer (score 1):

@RokoC.Buljan helped and all i had to do was add

```
#prev.colorBlackWhenLight, #next.colorBlackWhenLight { 
color: var(--black);
}
```